# Convert Database Linq Query Results to String List

Tags: vb.net, list, linq

I am trying to use a LINQ query to grab some data from a database, and since I am grabbing just one column of data I want to store it within a string list.  This is the code I have.

```
Dim POList As New List(Of String)
Using dbContext As New DBLINQDataContext
    Dim query = (From o In dbContext.Orders
                 Where o.Order_Number.StartsWith(JobNumber)
                 Select o.Order_Number)
    POList = query.ToList()
End Using
MessageBox.Show(POList.ToString())
```

When I run this the data in the MessageBox is

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

There is no table data, even though I know there are actual data points for me to be getting :\

Comment: @ParvathiKrishnan I saw that, tried it already, and got the same results as above.

Comment: Calling `ToString` on a list will give you the type name, not the entire contents of the list. You need to look around the list and display each item one by one.

Comment: @DavidG Thank you!  I wasn't sure what I was doing wrong was with how I was trying to display the list, or how I was doing the query.

Comment: You could replace `POList.ToString()` with `String.Join(",", POList)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`POList.ToString()` will display the name of the object type. 
You can use `string.Join(",", POList.ToString())`.

You can also define an extension method `StringJoin()` to show your list as string if you are going to use it frequently.

Here is an extension method that you can use:

```
public static StringExtensions
{
public static string StringJoin(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string seperator)
        {
            if (strings == null) return null;
            return string.Join(seperator, strings);
        }
}
```

Comment: 'StringJoin' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'

Comment: I believe @vend meant `string.Join(", ", POList)`

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for correction here. I have this `StringJoin` extension method that I use for `string.Join()`;

Comment: @DavidG Why it is overkill? It's a re-usable piece of code.

Comment: Well now you have 4 lines of code where you previously only needed one. But I'm not totally against it, I would have named it `Join` though to match the existing static method.

Comment: Thanks.. updated my answer with both choices and more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Since this was a vb.net question, I translated @vendettamit 's excellent answer for the benifit of future vb readers.

```
Public Module StringExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Function StringJoin(MyStrings As IEnumerable(Of String), separator As String) As String
        If MyStrings Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        Else
            Return String.Join(separator, MyStrings)
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

To use the extension...

```
Dim l As New List(Of String) From {"Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"}
Dim s As String = l.StringJoin(", ")
Debug.Print(s)
```